# Try to write a short version of this datetime comparison in Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby

I have a time comparison method I would like to have in my class.
I have this long long line of code. For all you rubyist out there, what would be a more elegant way of writing this line?

```
self.profile.videoconfavailability.wday == Date.today.wday &&
  self.profile.videoconfavailability.time >= Time.now + (60*60) &&
  Date.today.wday &&
  self.profile.videoconfavailability.time > Time.now
```

Comment: What exactly makes something elegant? That seems too subjective.

Comment: it seems to be way too long :(

Comment: It sounds to me, it has to be the question for [CodeReview community](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you own both the Profile and the VideoConfAvailability class definitions. If so, you're checking a lot of things on the VideoConfAvailability object so it may make sense to let that do the heavy lifting:

```
class VideoConfAvailability
  def available_on?(date: Date.today, minimum_notice: 1.hour)
    wday == date.wday && time >= minimum_notice.from_now
  end
end
```

If you don't own VideoConfAvailability and cannot modify it then you could move it out to the Profile:

```
class Profile
  def video_conference_available?(date: Date.today, minimum_notice: 1.hour)
    videoconfavailability.wday == date.wday &&
      videoconfavailability.time >= minimum_notice.from_now
  end
end
```

I gave both of the above method(s) arguments with what looks to be sensible defaults based on your code. This makes the code more readable, flexible, and testable.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

As Cary pointed out in the below comment the OP may not be using Rails (or ActiveSupport more specifically) so the `hour.from_now` method(s) may not be available.

It is possible to use ActiveSupport for the date/time helpers by requiring the `active support` gem in your Gemfile and then add the following require to your code:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'
```

If you don't want to use ActiveSupport you may want to use the Chronic gem and update the signature to take a time string, e.g.

```
class VideoConfAvailability
  def available_on?(date: Date.today, minimum_notice: '1 hour from now')
    wday == date.wday && time >= Chronic.parse(minimum_notice)
  end
end
```

If you don't want to use any libraries and do it all in base line Ruby then you can always re-introduce a multiplier to `Time.now + (60 * 60)`, but that makes the interface less flexible as you may have to specify a more granular unit of time, e.g.

```
class VideoConfAvailability
  def available_on?(date: Date.today, minimum_notice_in_minutes: 60)
    wday == date.wday && time >= Time.now + (60 * minimum_notice_in_minutes)
  end
end
```

I expanded the name of the `minimum_notice` argument since it is not clear looking at the signature (or at a call-site to this method) what the unit of time would be in. As part of the signature it removes any guess work on behalf of the code reader.

Comment: @Phranics, you hit the nail on this one!! thank you for refactoring.

Comment: `Fixnum` has no method `hour`. Note there is no Rails tag.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
self.profile.videoconfavailability.time >= Time.now + (60*60)
```

is `true` then

```
self.profile.videoconfavailability.time > Time.now
```

will be `true`, so you don't need the latter.

```
Date.today.wday
```

will always return a truthy value, so it's not needed either. You are left with

```
avail = self.profile.videoconfavailability
avail.wday == Date.today.wday && avail.time >= Time.now + 3600
```

Note `self.` is not needed, as `self` is implied when there is no explicit receiver.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def available_to_video_conf
    self.profile.videoconfavailability != nil
    starttime = self.profile.videoconfavailability.time.to_f
    endtime = (starttime + (60*60)).to_f
    time = Time.now
    starttime <= time.to_f && endtime >=starttime && 

    self.profile.videoconfavailability.time.day == Time.now.day

  end
```

Comment: I have to answer my own question here, dealing with date and time is not that easy for a beginner in Ruby.